# How to display columns in CSV file in python using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have the following CSV file:

[image]

I aim to show just the following columns: Date, Inbound and Outbound. For that, I'm using `pandas` to get what I want.

My code is the following:

```py
path_input = 'CSR1 - Traffic - 10.10.1.1 (Tunnel0).csv'
data = pd.read_csv(path_input,sep='\t')
data.columns = ["Date", "Inbound", "Outbound"]
```

I'm having this error:

```
----> 3 data.columns = ["Date", "Inbound", "Outbound"]
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 3 elements
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you need skip first rows:

```
data = pd.read_csv(path_input,sep='\t', skiprows=9)
```

Or specify row for new header, e.g. `10th` row:

```
data = pd.read_csv(path_input,sep='\t', header=[10])
```